# Django Framework Simple Class

Tags: python-3.x, django

Sorry to bother but first time posting here and very very new to Django, very very new to Python, possibly very new to the Internet :|

I'm currently learning Django and I setup a Django Project like so:

- app_admin/ and inside this folder it has the default urls.py, settings.py, wsgi.py etc..

I created an app and so now I have:

- app_admin/
- app_name/ and inside this folder views.py, models.py etc...

I read that it's best to keep your apps separated but now when I try to import any Classes from models.py even within app_name/ let's say a file main.py. When I try to do an *from .models import class-name* I get these errors that it cannot import django.db

My biggest confusion is what does the difference between *django-admin startproject APP* and then you can create an app like so *python3 manage.py startapp APP*. I'm quite confused about this. I want to build an app that can retrieve server info like python version, ip of server, kernel version, apache version etc... and I am trying to follow best practices but I guess I am not quite sure what I am doing :/ I am very stupid so please forgive me.

Comment: Hello sir, do you added your app name in the settings.py file?

Comment: Yes I did add and that part seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't apologise, you're not stupid. Programming is hard, we all know, and asking questions is a great way to learn. I would like to see your errors and file structure though just to be clear?

So basically, `python manage.py startproject` initialises a root directory folder where, if you enter this folder, there is a second project directory with the same name. Under this second directory, you can register all your different apps for this project in one place here. You need to register the urls of the apps in the urls.py file and register each app in the settings.py. For example:

app_admin settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'app_name',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

app_admin urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("app_name.urls")),
]
```

This will ensure that all of your URL's created in your App folder are registered within the main project

`python manage.py startapp`, on the other hand, creates a new app inside the root directory (on the same level as the project folder, or your 'app_admin' folder). It is here you will likely be writing most of your code through templates, models and views. This is different from the project folder mainly because you may have multiple apps in one project. You can think of the project folder as one convenient place to group all your apps and apply settings to them, such as using a custom authentication user model or using a different database.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I appreciate the explanation. Ok so it seems what I hard thought was correct in that the root project is sort of an admin  workspace to manage all your apps you plan to deploy. My problem is that  within app_name/models.py I have a Class. Inside this folder app_name I created a main.py file which I tried to import that Class by doing from .models import Class. I keep  getting this error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: However, if I create this main.py file and place it at the root of the project and do a from app_name.models import Class then it works. I guess I am trying to figure out that part. My settings file does have this: "BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.paren" and something tells me that the modules are only resolveable from the root folder. Is that correct? How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi eljoeyjojo, did you find out what the issue was? Care to share it? What is the error that shows?

Comment: hey @Richard Quigley, I haven't found an answer to this yet. If I create a main.py at the root of my project then I am able to import any models but once in an app/ doing any kind of from this import that... 
just keeps complaining that it can't find it. I need to learn more about Django.